# Filter @OneToMany in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `@OneToMany` relationship:

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="\MyApp\Entities\Content", mappedBy="clist")
 * @OrderBy({"contentOrder"="ASC", "id"="ASC"})
 */
private $contents;
```

I get all the `Content`'s, which `clist` attribute is the id of the current instance. But the `Content` class has an `isDeleted` attribute also. If it is set to true, I would like to exclude it from the list.

How is it possible?
I can filter the list in the `getContents()` function, but I hope there is a better solution. Maybe somehow in the definition of the `@OneToMany` relationship

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1**

I recommend using [Criteria](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) to filter collections

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

$clist = $entityManager->find('Clist', $clistId);
$contentCollection = $clist->getContents();

$criteria = Criteria::create()
   ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("isDeleted", false))
;

$undeletedContents = $contentCollection->matching($criteria);
```

**Option 2**

Another option could be to use [Filters](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html#filters) where you can make sure that as long as the filter is active each and every Query is making sure that a 'where' constraint is attached.

This usually makes sense if you have some attributes which are queried most of the time for most of your entities (like e.g. a ClientId or a Deleted attribute).

Answer (score 4):

If you are using ArrayCollection to store your relations then you can do this:

```
$criteria = Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("isDeleted", false));
$contents = $yourMainClass->getContents()->matching($criteria);
```

Hope this helps,

Alexandru Cosoi